# get value from XML File in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, xml

I have an XML File with the following format:

```
<containers>
    <container>
        <item>
            item name
        </item>
        <item>
            item name
        </item>
        <item>
            item name
        </item>
    </container>
    <container>
        <item>
            item name
        </item>
    </container>
</containers>
```

I need to use javascript to get the first item name in the second container. I was going to use `xmldoc.getElementsByTagName("item")[3].childNodes[0].nodeValue;` but I have no way of knowing how many items will be in the first container, so I'm looking for a way to select the second container then the item's name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, select the container tags. If you have 2 or more container tags, take the first child node of the second container. Something like this (may not be exact, haven't tested it):

```
var containers = xmldoc.getElementsByTagName("container");
if (containers.length >= 2)
{
  var items = containers[1].getElementsByTagName("item");
  if (items.length > 0)
  {
     //your item is items[0]
  }
}
```

Comment: I think that's just what I was looking for to get me back on track. Had a mental block and haven't been able to get past it until now.
Thanks!

Comment: Is there a way to distinguish between a container in a container? eg. if that first container has a container inside it, that have the index of 1...