# How to get XML values in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, xml

I want to access each lat and log value of this XML file using JavaScript and AJAX. Is there anyway I can loop through each of the values and display them? I already did the AJAX part. Would really appreciate your help. Thanks.

```
           $.ajax({
                 type:'get',
                 url: "2017-04-25_163304_assign2017.gpx",
                 data: {
                    key: "value"
                    },
                 dataType: "xml",
                 success: function(xml){

                 }
```

---

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<gpx version="1.0" creator="Ultra GPS Logger" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://www.topografix.com/GPX/1/0" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.topografix.com/GPX/1/0 http://www.topografix.com/GPX/1/0/gpx.xsd">
<trk>
<name><![CDATA[assign2017]]></name>
<trkseg>
<trkpt lat="35.876466" lon="14.508177"><ele>134.75</ele><time>2017-04-25T14:33:30Z</time></trkpt>
<trkpt lat="35.876254" lon="14.508889"><ele>-30.52</ele><time>2017-04-25T14:33:31Z</time></trkpt>
<trkpt lat="35.876147" lon="14.509038"><ele>-13.17</ele><time>2017-04-25T14:33:33Z</time></trkpt>
<trkpt lat="35.876170" lon="14.508932"><ele>99.07</ele><time>2017-04-25T14:33:34Z</time></trkpt>
</trkseg>
</trk>
</gpx>
```

Comment: getElementsByTagName and a loop

Comment: Related: [How to retrieve xml data from Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10684145/how-to-retrieve-xml-data-from-javascript) – [get value from XML File in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2211837/get-value-from-xml-file-in-javascript) – [Get node value in XML using jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20136280/get-node-value-in-xml-using-jquery) – [How to find/extract data from xml with jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2563101/how-to-find-extract-data-from-xml-with-jquery)

Comment: Quite easy as your using jQuery: [AJAX / Jquery XML parse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10223865/ajax-jquery-xml-parse)